# How to test GWT-server methods which call REST-service?

Tags: java, rest, gwt, jersey

I have these GWT-server classes:

**AbstractServiceImpl.class**

```
package org.foxclient.gwt.server;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import org.foxclient.gwt.client.answer.DataEvent;
import org.foxclient.gwt.client.service.GenericService;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


public abstract class AbstractServiceImpl<T, F> extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GenericService<T, F> {
    public abstract String getRequestURL();
    public abstract Integer getId(T object);

    public DataEvent delete(T object) {
        DataEvent event = new DataEvent();
        if ((object != null) && (getId(object) != null)) {
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(getRequestURL() + "/" + getId(object));
            ClientResponse response = webResource.delete(ClientResponse.class);
            event.setStatus(response.getStatus());
            event.setMessage("Success");
        } else {
            event.setStatus(404);
            event.setMessage("Not found");
        }
        return event;
    }

    @Override
    public DataEvent update(T object) {
        DataEvent event = new DataEvent();
        if ((object != null) && (getId(object) != null)) {
            ClientConfig clientConfig =  new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(getRequestURL() + "/" + getId(object));
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                    put(ClientResponse.class, object);
            event.setStatus(response.getStatus());
            event.setMessage("Success");
        } else {
            event.setStatus(404);
            event.setMessage("Not found");
        }
        return event;
    }

    @Override
    public DataEvent add(T object) {
        DataEvent event = new DataEvent();
        if (object != null) {
            ClientConfig clientConfig =  new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(getRequestURL());
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                                                  post(ClientResponse.class, object);
            if ((response.getStatus() == 200)) {
                event.setStatus(200);
                event.setMessage("Success");
            } else {
                event.setStatus(response.getStatus());
                event.setMessage("Some error");
            }
        } else {
            event.setStatus(400);
            event.setMessage("No data");
        }
        return event;
    }
}
```

**DepartmentServiceImpl.java**

```
package org.foxclient.gwt.server;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import org.foxclient.gwt.client.answer.DepartmentListEvent;
import org.foxclient.gwt.client.answer.DataEvent;
import org.foxclient.gwt.client.entity.Department;
import org.foxclient.gwt.client.entity.Filter;
import org.foxclient.gwt.client.service.DepartmentService;

import java.util.List;

public class DepartmentServiceImpl extends AbstractServiceImpl<Department, Filter> implements DepartmentService {

    public String getRequestURL() {
        return "http://localhost:8080/foxrestful/rest/departments";
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId(Department object) {
        return object.getId();
    }

    public DataEvent getAll() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

        WebResource resource = client.resource(getRequestURL());
        ClientResponse response = resource.get(ClientResponse.class);
        DepartmentListEvent event = new DepartmentListEvent();
        if ((response.getStatus() == 200) && response.hasEntity()) {
            event.setStatus(200);
            event.setDepartments(response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Department>>() { }));
        } else {
            event.setStatus(response.getStatus());
            event.setMessage("Some error");
        }
        return event;
    }

    @Override
    public DataEvent getFiltered(Filter filter) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want test methods **getAll(), delete(T object)** and etc. But they call remote REST-service and I can't intercept this call. Also, I think, I can't mock WebResource because it's a inner logic of method which I want test. Maybe I can pick up REST-server and redirect to it?

**Have any ideas how I can test these methods?**

I use GWT 2.7.0 as a client for my remote REST-service (it written by Jersey 1.19). Also, as you can see, I use Jersey client for get responses from service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`getAll(), delete(T object)` these two methods are network related method so you need to implement `async` operation to test network related operation

it should ideally be used for operations that take few seconds. Some tasks keep the thread running for long time so in that case it is recommended to use java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Comment: Thank you for advice. But my question is how I can test this methods?